# Browser: Defined location.search / location.href encoding?

Tags: javascript, browser, encoding, cross-browser, urlencode

Question regarding **javascript properties** `window.location.search` / `window.location.href` **[within a browser](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)**:

Are there any **guarantees / specifications** regarding the **returned values** of both expressions
if they are **[percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)** (URL encoding) or not?

Or is this browser-dependent and/or context-dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not find official specs nor answers to my question here:

After doing tests in all major browsers (current version only), it looks like both properties are always returning the original, possibly percentage-encoded URL.